# Mysql returning multiple row instead of one row with array of Images

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

CREATE TABLE attachments (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  filePath VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  thumbnailPath VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

CREATE TABLE reviews (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  productId INT NULL,
  user_id INT NULL,
  review VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  rating INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE review_attachments (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  review_id INT NULL,
  attachment_id INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES 
('1', 'XYZ'),
('2', 'ABC'),
('3', 'EVE');


INSERT INTO attachments (id, name, filePath, thumbnailPath) VALUES 
('100', 'f.png', '/resources/attachments/2020/f.png', '/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/f.png'),
('101', 'd.png', '/resources/attachments/2020/d.png', '/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/d.png'),
('102', 'g.png', '/resources/attachments/2020/g.png', '/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/g.png');

INSERT INTO reviews (id, productId, user_id, review, rating) VALUES 
('1', '1', '1', 'Great Product', '5'),
('2', '1', '2', 'Good Product', '4'),
('3', '1', '3', 'Bad Product', '1');

INSERT INTO review_attachments (id, review_id, attachment_id) VALUES 
('1', '1', '100'),
('2', '1', '101'),
('3', '1', '102');
```

When I query against this schema using the following query I am getting two rows with the same entries.

I am using JSON_ARRAYAGG to return an array it may be because of groupby.

Can anyone help me get this query right?

```
select
    review, rating, u.name,reviews.createdAt,
    (SELECT 
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("attachmentId", attachments.id,
        'filePath', TRIM(CONCAT("${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}", '/',attachments.filePath)),
        'thumbnailPath', TRIM(CONCAT("${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}", '/',attachments.thumbnailPath))
        ))
        FROM attachments
        WHERE attachments.id = ra.attachment_id) as reviewAttachments
            
from reviews
    left join users as u on u.id = reviews.user_id
    left join reviewAttachments as ra on ra.review_id = reviews.id
    left join attachments as at on at.id = ra.attachment_id
where productId = 1
and reviews.isDeleted =0 
and reviews.review is not null
limit 0,5

|review        |rating| name  | createdAt | reviewAttachments | 
|:----         |:----:| -----:| ---------:| ----------------:
|Great Product | 5    |  XYZ  | 2020-11-04| [{"filePath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/2020/f.png", "attachmentId": 102, "thumbnailPath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/f.png"}]
|Great Product | 5    |  XYZ  | 2020-11-04| [{"filePath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/2020/d.png", "attachmentId": 101, "thumbnailPath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/d.png"}]
|Great Product | 5    |  XYZ  | 2020-11-04| [{"filePath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/2020/g.png", "attachmentId": 100, "thumbnailPath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/g.png"}]
|Good Product  | 4    |  ABC  | 2020-11-04| null
|Bad Product   | 1    |  EVE  | 2020-11-04| null
```

Desired output:

```
|review        |rating| name  | createdAt | reviewAttachments | 
|:----         |:----:| -----:| ---------:| ----------------:
|Great Product | 5    |  XYZ  | 2020-11-04| [{"filePath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/2020/f.png", "attachmentId": 102, "thumbnailPath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/f.png"}, {"filePath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/2020/d.png", "attachmentId": 101, "thumbnailPath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/d.png"}, {"filePath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/2020/g.png", "attachmentId": 100, "thumbnailPath": "${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}/resources/attachments/thumbnail/2020/g.png"}] 
|Good Product  | 4    |  ABC  | 2020-11-04| null
|Bad Product   | 1    |  EVE  | 2020-11-04| null
```

Notice: The above row with rating 5 is returning array of reviewAttachments associated with that review. My output is returning each row with duplicate entries of that rating with different review attachment.

Comment: @Strawberry Hey I have added the create and insert statements as well. Can you help me with the query?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you still don't say precisely what your desired output is - although FWIW, I would handle the array manipilation in application code

Comment: Also, as things like `${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}` are clearly irrelevant to the problem, and just take up space and reduce legibility, I would just omit them altogether.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the desired output. I have made another query for getting the review attachments. Its working fine. But the catch is I have to run it within a for loop which i don't prefer. Can you help me with the above query?

Comment: What's wrong with a loop?

Comment: Nothing when the dataset is small. But once it scales it takes too much time too execute.

Comment: That *might* be a flaw with the design of the loop

Comment: @VishalKumar, Just made a minor change to your query - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uZgWjur4cmqwUjuLPcCNP5/0. See if it helps?

Comment: @Prasanna Thanks mate it did work. You can post your answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    review, rating, u.name,
    (SELECT 
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("attachmentId", attachments.id,
        'filePath', TRIM(CONCAT("${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}", '/',attachments.filePath)),
        'thumbnailPath', TRIM(CONCAT("${process.env.NODE_SERVER_API_HOST}", '/',attachments.thumbnailPath))
        ))
        FROM review_attachments ra
        left join attachments on attachments.id = ra.attachment_id                            
        WHERE ra.review_id = reviews.id) as reviewAttachments     
from reviews
    left join users as u on u.id = reviews.user_id
where productId = 1
and reviews.review is not null
limit 0,5
```